# Why do my components look like Windows Classic?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When I make a Windows Form Application and drag in a button component it shows it normally like any other button on Windows 10. But when I compile it and run it shows like it like this?

(Yes, I did in-fact do Application.EnableVisualStyles before running the form)

[image]

Comment: Make sure you can reproduce the problem in a totally new clean project by simply adding a `Button` to `Form1` using designer.

Comment: I did, I had re-tested this 3 times already. All the same results!

Comment: did you change the flatstyle of the button?

Comment: And whats Window's configuration? You can switch off all visual styles to improve performance.

Comment: and what about your windows and all programs running, are all different (not classic view)? may be try the app on a different machine

Comment: Yes! I had tried everything you said. I had resolved the problem, thank you for trying to help! Apparently naming the form a windows system process had changed it's style..?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved! Apparently creating a new type of C# application then disregarding and then creating a Windows Forms Application worked. Weird, but works!

EDIT:
Actually, naming your form to svchost or any system process in Windows 10 will change it's style.. apparently.